# Trigger REST adapter to push records to store

Tags: ember.js, websocket, ember-data, web2py

I have the following setup:

1. The ember frontend is connected to a websocket server
2. The backend pushes records (real-time data) via websocket to the clients, as stringified JSON
3. The client receives the data, and must now update the store with this new data received

The problem that I have is that I do not know to process the raw JSON data to make it compatible to  what is in the store. I can of course parse the json (`JSON.parse`), but this is just a part of what the REST adapter is doing.

When doing a normal REST request, more or less what happens is that:

```
server generates reply -> REST adapter converts it -> it gets pushed to the store
```

But now, since I am not using the REST adapter to process this data (because this is not a request triggered in the client side, but a notification coming from the server side), I do not know how to trigger the normal processing that the REST adapter performs.

- How can I trigger the REST adapter programmatically? Can I pass it the stringified JSON coming from the websockets server?
- Is it possible to hook the REST adapter to a generic websockets callback, where the only thing I have is the stringified JSON coming from the websockets server?

This is the code that I have (inspired in `web2py`)

```
function connect_websocket() {
    console.log('connect_websocket > connecting to server');
    var callback = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        console.log('Data received > data=%o', data);
        // TODO;
        //  - process the data as the REST adapter would do, and push new / updated records to the store.
        //  - handle record deletes too (how?)
    };
    if(!$.web2py.web2py_websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8888/realtime/mygroup', callback)) {
        alert('html5 websocket not supported by your browser, try Google Chrome');
    }
}
```

I have taken a look at [EmberSockets](https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberSockets), but as far as I understand that does not offer a generic method of updating records in the store, but just a very specialized way of updating properties in the controllers (which requires a lot of configuration too).

What I am looking for is a generic method of triggering the ember REST adapter from a websockets server. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Have you seen this: https://gist.github.com/brentjanderson/4360857 Looks like a solid start or even a working solution for a socket.io adapter extension.

Comment: Check also push & pushPayload http://emberjs.com/guides/models/frequently-asked-questions/#toc_how-do-i-inform-ember-data-about-new-records-created-on-the-backend

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte: thanks, but that seems to be a re-implementation of the REST adapter on top of websockets (that is, it is a request-reply implementation, not a push implementation). Some ideas can be obtained from it though.

Comment: @Altrim: thanks, I am taking a look at that now.